# Read from a file which has integer values in every separate line and then if a condition is met execute a statement

Tags: shell-script, files

I have a text file which has only integer values i.e different integers in different lines(say from 1 to 47). I have made a script that would read each line and take the value present in a different line. If the condition is met, then I want to echo a statement.

contents of **a.txt**: (In one line there is only 1, In second line there is only 2, as is) 1 2 3 4 5 ..so on till 47.

**Output** I want: As soon it reads 5. Output - "Step Completed is 5" (without double quotes) . This should go for 5,10,15,20 till 45

Here is the code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 #!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
        if [[ $line=="5" ]] ; then
           echo "Step Completed is:" $var
        fi
done < "$1"
```

Also I want to echo the same statement for every 5 integer values i.e as soon as the script reads 5, it should echo - Step completed is 5. As soon as it reads 10, it should echo - Step Completed is 10. Like this.

To run the script I am using the command:

```
. ./al.sh a.txt
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input file and the desired output?

Comment: a.txt: (In one line there is only 1, In second line there is only 2, as is) 
1
2
3
4
5
..so on till 47. 

Output I want: As soon it reads 5. Output - "Step Completed is 5" (without double quotes) . This should go for 5,10,15,20 till 45

Comment: @Tanmay can you edit the question and add the content you have given in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output a "step completed" everything 5 lines, then takes the rest of the step number when divided by 5 and compare to 0:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; 
do
        if [[ $(( line %5 )) -eq  0 ]] ; then
        echo "Step Completed is: $line"
        fi
done < "$1"
```

(not also that in your script you variable is called `line` or `var`....)

If you want only the last such line, then you have to wait until the end to print it. If you have a complete sequence of number then you can compute it at the end:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; 
do
    # do whatever for the line
    echo $line >/dev/null
done < "$1"
echo "Step completed is: $(( 5 * ( line % 5 ) ))"
```

Otherwise just remember the last on you saw:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; 
do
    [[ $(( line %5 )) -eq  0 ]] && line5=$line 
    # do whatever for the line
done < "$1"
[[ ! -z "$line5" ]]  && echo "Step completed is: $line5"
```

Comment: Since he's sourcing the script, the `#!`-line is not needed (unless he later wants to run it in the more ordinary way).

Comment: `if (( line % 3 == 0 )); then` should also work, i.e. you can do the comparison in the arithmetic expansion too. For completeness' sake, you could add a check to see if the line read is numeric.

Comment: I want it in such a way that if 10 is found so it shouldn't print - Step Completed : 5. If 20 is found, it shouldn't print 5,10,15. Just print the last line which on modulus with 5 gives 0.

Comment: See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this in a shell script, I'd suggest doing it with `awk`:

```
awk '$1 % 5 == 0 { last_step = $1 } END { printf("Step %s completed\n", last_step ) }' <a.txt
```

This keeps the code short, fast, and simple.  The `awk` code stores each multiple of 5 that it finds in its input, and at the end it prints the most recent such number found.

Testing (in a shell that has brace expansions):

```
$ printf '%s\n' {1..47} | awk '$1 % 5 == 0 { last_step = $1 } END { printf("Step %s completed\n", last_step ) }'
Step 45 completed
```

The equivalent shell loop would look like

```
while read number; do
    if [ "$(( number % 5 ))" -eq 0 ]; then
        last_step=$number
    fi
done <a.txt

printf 'Step %s completed\n' "$last_step"
```

You may want to insert a test to make sure that `last_step` has a valid value before doing any output, or you will get bogus output if your input contains no multiples of five.

Comment: I want it in such a way that if 10 is found so it shouldn't print - Step Completed : 5. If 20 is found, it shouldn't print 5,10,15. Just print the last line which on modulus with 5 gives 0.

Comment: @Tanmay Ah, this was not clear from the question.  Just a moment...  There, fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. Sorry for keeping some part of the question ambiguous.